# Different marginal effects for factor and dummies

Tags: stata, margins, dummy-variable

Can someone explain why I get different marginal, i.e. discrete, effects (but identical coefficients) for the following commands. I tried to create a dataset to replicate this finding.

```
clear
set seed 123456
set obs 4

gen factor = 0 if _n == 1
replace factor = 1 if _n == 2
replace factor = 2 if _n == 3
replace factor = 3 if _n == 4

gen dummy1 = 0
replace dummy1 = 1 if factor == 1
gen dummy2 = 0
replace dummy2 = 1 if factor == 2
gen dummy3 = 0
replace dummy3 = 1 if factor == 3

expand 10

gen dv = 5 + rnormal()

gen b = 0
replace b = 1 if dv > 6

quietly logit b i.factor, robust
margins, dydx(*)
quietly logit b i.dummy1 i.dummy2 i.dummy3, robust
margins, dydx(*)
```

Why are the marginal effects in both cases different?

Comment: In the second example, Stata is not aware that a change in dummy1 requires changes in dummy2 and dummy3, since only one of them can be one. Full use of factor variable notation, as in the first example, allows Stata to understand how the independent variables are related to each other.

Comment: Then why is this not an issue for the linear case (reg, with dependent variable dv)?